# Xamarin iOS Debug Native Static Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.ios, interop

I have a Xamarin.iOS solution in Visual Studio that includes a couple C++ static library references. I have built these myself and have access to the source C++, and I know that debugging [is possible in VC++ iOS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/04/29/debugging-c-code-on-ios-with-visual-studio-2015/). My C# code integrates with the libraries using PInvoke `DllImport`. Is there a way to debug these libraries using Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm looking at http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html now. Maybe that will work instead?

Comment: Have you found the solution. I think we can debug it in VS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517093/9125096

Comment: I don't see that option in Xamarin.iOS projects, nor do I see it in my C# (.NET Standard) project that contains the `DllImport`. I think that's referring to projects targeting .NET Framework.

Comment: I have been using LLDB to debug the simulator. It's not as nice as VS, but it is my only option at this point.